# Parsing JSON with *ngfor directive in HTML

Tags: javascript, json, angular, ionic2

I would like to be able to get and list the **keys** (not **values**) from the **params** array in this JSON Object, using the ***ngfor** directive in an ionic2 page.

```
{
 "id":"x",
 "name":"xxx",
 "code":"xxx",
 "description":"xxx",
 "params":
         [
          {"param1": "params1"},
          {"param2": "params2"},
          {"param3": "params3"}
         ]
}
```

I have searched around this forum and found an implementation using pipes; but I have been unsuccessful so far. The most I've been able to obtain using the pipes are the array indexes, but not the **keys**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { PipeTransform , Pipe } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe( { name : 'keys' } )
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform ( value , args : string[] ) : any {
        let keys = [];
        for ( let key in value ) {
            if ( value.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
                keys.push( key );
            }
        }
        return keys;
    }
}
```

And use it like this :

```
                       <ul>
                          <li *ngFor="let item of obj.params  ">
                           <span  *ngFor="let key of item | keys  ">{{key  }}</span>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
```

Here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/W3bRuJdcCqM4bd5Jlbcm?p=preview)

Note that plunker is using # , you should use let instead , like above.

Comment: Will, give this a quick try and get back to you @Milad

Comment: unfortunately same as before, I get the array indexes. So instead of param1, param2, param3 I get 0,1,2.

Comment: Works like a charm!!! you're my hero right now! Thanks a lot and Merry Christmas!